# persistentvolumeclaim "pv-delay-bind" not found kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I specified:

#### This is Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
         ...
          volumeMounts:
            - name: volumepath
              mountPath: /data
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
      volumes:
        - name: volumepath
          persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: pv-delay-bind
```

#### This is persistentvolume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-delay-bind
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/
    type: DirectoryOrCreate
  storageClassName: default1a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) is different from a [Persistent Volume Claim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistentvolumeclaims). Typically, when you use persistent volume claim you are using [dynamic](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/#using-dynamic-provisioning) provisioning.

So you would need to define the persistent volume claim first and the volume should be created automatically.

First, delete your volume if you don't need it.

```
$ kubectl delete volume pv-delay-bind
```

Then create the claim:

```
$ echo '
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv-delay-bind
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: default1a' | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: The kind of pvc is PersistentVolumeClaim not PersistentVolume

Comment: Ahh thanks! I've corrected it!

Comment: thx bro i do it !!